# How to pass/retrive local var in rails 3.1.0 partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is code in form.html.erb for partial view. Local var :sid was defined as the id of the record and it should be passed into the partial view standards.html.erb as a local var.

```
  <% @rfq.standards.each do |r| %>  
    <p><%= render :partial => 'standards', :locals => { :f => f, :sid => r.id } %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the standards partial view:

```
  <%= f.association :standards, :collection => Standard.active_std.all(:order => 'name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, 
                                :prompt => "Choose std", :label => "standard：", :include_blank => true, :selected => :sid %>
```

When rendered, standards partial view should render a collection of standards with sid selected. However the code above does not select the standards at all. Tried sid (string) :selected => sid. This causes error saying that sid was not defined.

My question is what's the right way to pass and retrieve a local var in view? Thanks so much.

Comment: You should use in the partials view: `..., :selected => sid %>`, because `sid` is in your partials view a local variable. `:sid` cannot work, because it is just a symbolic value. Your usage of `render :partial ...` looks ok for me, however.

Comment: I did extensively search online about locals and almost everyone says use locals and access it with it name in partial. However sid somehow was not defined in partial and can not be accessed. Is there other way to pass the var into partial? Thanks so much.

Comment: The reason is that the partial standards were not called in each and every place with exactly the same format. In one method (not shown here), the standards was called like: render :partial => standards, :locals => {:f => f}. After adding :sid => 0, the sid here is passed in successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the partial standards were not called in each and every place with exactly the same format. In one method (not shown here), the partial standards was called like: `render :partial => standards, :locals => {:f => f}`. After adding :sid => 0 as `render :partial => standards, :locals => {:f => f, :sid => 0}`, the sid here is passed in successfully.